# Trouble with foreach loop through image

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to make a foreach loop that is taking all the image, when I debug the code I can see that it takes the images corect but not all is comming to the database. If I choose 3 images only 2 comes in the database and third one is only have the path, but not the image.

Can someone help me.

Here is my code in my Photo model :

```
public class Photo
{
    public int PhotoId { get; set; }

    public String ProfileImagePath { get; set; }

    public int StudentId { get; set; }

    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }

    public void SaveImage(HttpPostedFileBase image,
        String serverPath, String pathToFile)
    {
        if (image == null) return;

        string filename = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        ImageModel.ResizeAndSave(
            serverPath + pathToFile, filename,
            image.InputStream, 200);

        ProfileImagePath = pathToFile + filename +
        ".jpg";
    }


}
```

And here is my controller code :

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "StudentId,Name,Adress")] Student student,
        HttpPostedFileBase[] image)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {


            foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in image)
            {

                string filePathToSave = "/ProfileImages/";
                photo.SaveImage(file, HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~"), "/ProfileImages/");
                photo = new Photo
                {
                    StudentId = student.StudentId,
                    Student = student,
                    ProfileImagePath = filePathToSave
                };
                 db.Photos.Add(photo);
            }
            db.Students.Add(student);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(student);
    }
```

Comment: Something is not right with the code you have shown. You call `photo.SaveImage(..)` before you have declared `photo = new Photo()` so that would throw an exception. And since `SaveImage()` sets the value of the `ProfileImagePath` property, why are you then setting it again (to a different value) using `ProfileImagePath = filePathToSave`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not shown the correct code (what you have shown will throw an exception) so I assume you must have declared

```
Photo photo = new Photo();
```

somewhere before your `photo.SaveImage(..)` line which is likely to be the source the error. In addition, your `photo.SaveImage()` sets the value of `ProfileImagePath` (to say `.../ProfileImages/someGuid.jpg`) but then you overwrite it and replace it with just `/ProfileImages/` when you call `ProfileImagePath = filePathToSave`

Change you code to

```
var path = HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/ProfileImages"); // only need to set this once
foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in image)
{
    Photo photo = new Photo
    {
        StudentId = student.StudentId, // no need to set the Student property
    };
    photo.SaveImage(file, path); // this will set the ProfileImagePath property
    db.Photos.Add(photo);
}
```

and the `SaveImage()` method to

```
public void SaveImage(HttpPostedFileBase image, string path)
{
    if (image == null) return;
    string filename = string.Format("{0}.jpg", Guid.NewGuid());
    // not sure what the following line does to it may also need to be modified?
    ImageModel.ResizeAndSave(path, filename, image.InputStream, 200); 
    ProfileImagePath = Path.Combine(path, filename);
}
```

I would however consider moving the `SaveImage()` method out of the `Photo` class and into a separate service, especially as it seems to be calling a static method in another class.